# How can I match 4 repeating numbers using regex (PCRE)

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I would like to detect whether a user-chosen pin contains 4 identical numbers e.g 1111 or 2222. I'm using preg_match in PHP.

How can I adapt this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507982/regex-to-find-repeating-numbers) to do this?

Comment: Seeing as how the pin would usually not be embedded in any other data, isn't a non-regex approach of seeing if a string consists of the same, repeated value more maintainable for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting from the answer you link to:

```
\b(\d)\1{3}\b
```

Instead of using `\1+` that would match any number of repetitions of the first digit, you substitute it with `\1{3}` that will only allow three repetitions of the first digit, thus giving you the desired four digits when matched.

Or if you prefer:

```
\b(\d)\1\1\1\b
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use this regex:

```
/(\d)\1{3}/
```

This matches a single digit `(\d)`, and then matches that same digit 3 times `\1{3}`.

Comment: this is called back referencing http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php

Answer (score 2):

```
count(array_unique(str_split($pin))) > 1
```

Comment: I like this solution, but you'd have to make sure `$pin` consisted of only numbers beforehand and it's length is 4. Otherwise, things like `aaaa` and even `1` will validate.

Comment: Nice one, although I find it strange that you would need a regex or 3 string (or more?) functions just to check for 4 repeating numbers. I would have thought it would be simpler...

Comment: @nickb a pin typically is just 4 numbers, but I suppose it could be different in this case.