# Regular expression to detect numbers repeating in a row

Tags: javascript, regex

I cant realize and find a regular expression to detect sequences of repeated numbers (more than 2 times) like:

```
1111 or
a1111 or
test4555
```

Someone can help me please?

Comment: Might want to start here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507982/regex-to-find-repeating-numbers

Comment: It's silly to do this with a regular expression.  Just scan the string looking for repeated digits.

Comment: @NovaDenizen: Really?? I think this is actually a perfect situation that's calling for a regex.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write:

```
/(\d)\1\1/
```

where `\d` means "a digit", `(...)` means "capture (remember) what `...` matched", and `\1` means "what the first `(...)` captured".