# Detect numbers are Repetitive or not in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive to detect if numbers are Repetitive or not .
here is my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7htqdk7y/3/
  but it won't work , Any idea ?

**Directive**

```
app.directive('validTel', function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            if (!ngModelCtrl) {
                return;
            }

            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (val) {
                var clean = val.replace(/[11111111111+22222222222+a-z+@]+/g, '');
                if (val !== clean) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    console.log('hey');
                }
                return clean;
            });

            element.bind('keypress', function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode === 32) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

the rule is , user shouldn't enter Repetitive numbers like : `11111111111` or `22222222222`
**NOTE:** I have another directive that controls count of numbers like : my-`maxlentgh='11'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regexp you want is this one:

```
(1){11,}|(2){11,}|(3){11,}|(4){11,}|(5){11,}|(6){11,}|(7){11,}|(8){11,}|(9){11,}|(0){11,}
```

It means:

```
digit 1: 11 or more times
  or
digit 2: 11 or more times
  etc...
```

whereas

```
(\d){11,}
```

would mean: there are eleven or more digits in your string

Comment: how should i use it in directive ?

Comment: var clean = val.replace(/(1){11,}|(2){11,}|(3){11,}|(4){11,}|(5){11,}|(6){11,}|(7){11,}|(8){11,}|(9){11,}|(0){11,}/g, '') would erase a digit repeated 11 times or more, if this it what you mean to do

Comment: no i dont want to erase normal number like : 1234569878 or 02122411689 these are ok but 111111111111 these are not

Comment: var clean = val.replace(/(1){11,}|(2){11,}|(3){11,}|(4){11,}|(5){11,}|(6){11,}|(7){11,}|(8){‌​11,}|(9){11,}|(0){11,}/g, '')  would erase 11111111111,22222222222,33333333333 etc (up to 00000000000), but not other numbers like 12345678901

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you got the regex wrong. Try

```
var clean = var clean = val.replace(/[a-z+@]+/gi, '').replace(/(((\d){11,11})(\3)*)/g, '$2');
```

here is the modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7htqdk7y/4/

The second replace restricts digits to be repeated more then 11 times -- it strips all repetitions of a digit that are out of that scope.

I think that's a better solution than the accepted answer, because matches of repetitions aren't replaced completely, but only the part that we don't permit

See [Regex to find repeating numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507982/regex-to-find-repeating-numbers)

Comment: i'm not sure buddy , test it out