# Lua pattern to match similar consecutive digits

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I have a string that contains only digits from `2` to `9`, like `'223488875662264442'`, it is guaranteed that it does not contain more than 3 adjacent similar digits, for example, it cannot contain `'7777'`, but it can contain `'27747772'`.

I want to make a pattern that matches all the similar consecutive numbers, example:

```
    > str = '44788895532244474568884511123331566';
    > for n in string.gmatch(str,pat) do -- pat is the pattern
    >>    print(n);
    > end
    44
    7
    888
    9
    55
    ...
```

tried with patterns like `'(%d)%1*'` with no success.

I cannot use regex,I need to do it with Lua patterns.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to find repeating numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507982/regex-to-find-repeating-numbers)

Comment: You'll want to use `(\d)\1+` like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507982/regex-to-find-repeating-numbers

Comment: @Rossiar it's not a dupe since the OP is using Lua patterns and not regex, the solution won't work here so I've updated the question to remove mentions of regex.

Comment: `for n in str:gsub('.','%0%0\0'):gsub('(.)%z%1','%1'):gmatch'.(.-)%z' do`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff What does '%0%0\0' mean?

Comment: @RedouaneRed - It means "repeat captured character twice and append \0"