# Repeating number RegExp in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I get ['999'] out of this string? '451999277'? I only want repetitions of the same character.

This is what I've tried:

```
'451999277'.match(/(\d{3})/g) // === ["451", "999", "277"]
'451999277'.match(/(\d){3}/g) // === ["451", "999", "277"]
'451999277'.match(/([0-9]){3}/g) // === ["451", "999", "277"]
'451999277'.match(/(\d)\1{3}/g) // === null
```

.......

[EDIT]

solution:

```
'451999277'.match(/(\d)\1{2}/g) // ===  ['999']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to find repeating numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507982/regex-to-find-repeating-numbers)

Comment: `(\d)` matches one digit, `\1{3}` matches three digits, so `(\d)\1{3}` would require four digits to match.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks! This is the winner:  '451999277'.match(/(\d)\1{2}/g)

Comment: As a nit-pick, I object to your use of `===` in the comment.  I'd like to point out that even `['999'] === ['999']` is `false`.  We get what you meant though.

Comment: @Wyck ah yeah good point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there with your last example. If you just want groups of 3 use `{2}` instead of `{3}`:

```js
console.log('4519992277'.match(/(\d)\1{2}/g))

console.log('455519992277'.match(/(\d)\1{2}/g))
```