# MySQL REGEXP 3 times repeating characters

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I want to find string in mysql with 3 repeating character. I read all answers like here [Regex to find repeating numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507982/regex-to-find-repeating-numbers) but it does not work with MySQL 5.7:

```
select  '211' REGEXP '(.)\1\1'; //true but I expect false

select  '211' REGEXP '(.)\1{2}'; // true but I expect false

select  '211' REGEXP '([[:alnum:]])\1\1'; //true but I expect false

select  '211' REGEXP '(\w)\1{2}'; //false but

select  '111' REGEXP '(\w)\1{2}'; // also false
```

UPDATE: As tested it works as expected with MySQL 8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to find repeating numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507982/regex-to-find-repeating-numbers)

Comment: I tried. 'select  '211' REGEXP '(.)\\1\\1';' true

Comment: They work on 8.0 because 8.0 has a better REGEXP engine.  In particular, the backreference `\1` was not implemented before 8.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
select  '111' REGEXP '(\\w)\\1\\1';
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0aaa8ae048bb9d243173765c7e8755d9)

This query is Tested on Mysql 8 and Maria DB 10

For MySql 5.7 And Lower, I ended up with dirty workaround

```
select  
 CASE WHEN (
  @X:=SUBSTRING(C,1,1)) = @X and 
  @X=SUBSTRING(C,2,1) AND 
  @x=SUBSTRING(C,3,1)
 THEN 
  1 
 ELSE 
  0 
 END MyMatch
FROM
  (SELECT '111' c) T
```

Comment: I provided the working fiddle. It is working on Mysql 8

Comment: I use mysql 5.7 with mysql workbench 6.3. does it make difference?

Comment: It seems that there is difference. unfortunately, this is how mysql behaves

Comment: @SergioSerro Please check my solution for MySql 5.7 and below

Comment: If this answer is useful for you please consider to mark it as answer so that community can also benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

That could have been :

```
(.)\1{2}
```

Unfortunately, MySQL regexes do not support backreferences, so this will not work.

I guess that you would have to manually define all supported combinations and explicitly put them in the regex, like :

```
(000)|(111)|(222)|...|(999)|(aaa)|(bbb)|...|(zzz)
```

(you need to replace the ... with all other patterns)

If you want to identify strings that contain only 3 similar characters and nothing else, add « ^ » at the beginning of the regex and « $ » at the end.

Comment: SELECT '111' REGEXP '([[:digit:]])\1\1'; works well. MySQL supports backreferences sometimes

Comment: @SergioSerro : ok, then does « (.)\1{2} » work ? Also, which version of MySQL do you use ?

Comment: No, it does not (for mysql 5.7). Try ```SELECT '211' REGEXP '([[:digit:]])\1\1'```; For MySQL \1 is just 1