# Regular expression to find repeat number not working

Tags: android, regex

We want to check if number has repeat sequence for example - `111111` , `222222` etc. Below is the code :

```
String input = "222222";

public static String REGEX_REPEAT = "([\\d])\1{2}";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_REPEAT);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input.trim());
return matcher.matches();
```

But it always return false. I tried below regular expression also "`([\\d])\\1{2}`"

Any Help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [This answer might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6508030/9678116)

Comment: Same regular expression is working fine when I test it on online tool https://regex101.com/ .  But It is not working from android code. I try with various combinations thought escape character issue but nothing works.

Comment: @Androiddeveloper you can use this "^(\\d)\\1+$" Also added the answer.

Comment: The `matches` method checks the whole string. Use the `find` method instead.

Comment: (\\d)\\1{3,} This expression work for me. Hope it will help someone has same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
String REGEX_REPEAT = "([\\d])\1{2}";
```

with

```
String REGEX_REPEAT = "^(\\d)\\1+$";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

```
    import java.util.regex.*; 
class FindRepeatSequence {

    static boolean returnMatch(String input){
   String REGEX_REPEAT = "(\\w)\\1+";
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_REPEAT);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input.trim());
    return matcher.matches();
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
      String input = "222222";

     System.out.println("Print"+returnMatch(input));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check the duplicate just use

```
   (\d)\1+\b
```

and if you want to check duplicate with limit use

```
  //  (\d)\1{number_limit}\b   eg: 

     (\d)\1{3}\b
```

Comment: Not working in android code

Comment: are you using user_String.matches(regex)  ?    eg:   "11232332".matches("(\d)\1+\b ")

Comment: thie expression (\\d)\\1{3,} is working for me.