# Regular Expression For Duplicate Digits

Tags: java, regex, duplicates

what would be the regular expression to find duplicate set of digits in a numeric string?

Suppose

```
String s="0.1234523452345234";
```

From this string I need to obtain "2345". I tried the following regex-

```
String s="0.1234523452345234";
String regex="(\\d+)\\1+\\b";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m=p.matcher(s);
if(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

But the output is

> 523452345234

While i need to print

> 2345

Comment: i need the output string to contain the maximum length of unique digits that are repeating

Comment: i'm sorry, i forgot to mention "unique". 2345234 isn't the set of unique digits cause 234 at the end is already in the beginning

Comment: okay, thanks for trying!

Comment: @Shubham you can check my try

Comment: That's a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507982/regex-to-find-repeating-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"(\\d+)\\1+\\b"` macthes any sequence of digits followed immediately by this sequence at least once. It can be followed by multiple occurences of the sequence (the `+` quantifier). The regex also enforces a word boundary after the last matching sequence.

I think what you are looking for is the following regex:

`"(\\d+).*\\1"` (without word boundary, anything between your sequences, and only one repetition of the sequence. Example:

```
0.1234789897897123499
  ^^^^         ^^^^----  (\\d+) and \\1
      ^^^^^^^^^--------  .*
```

If your longest run needs to be followed immediately by the duplicate (no fillers inbetween), then drop the `.*` from the regex.

`group(0)` will return the full match (e.g. `12347898978971234`), `group(1)` will contain the first capturing group (e.g. `1234`).

Comment: yes, i needed the duplicates to be followed immediately

Answer (score 0):

I tried this regular expression that finds the number that duplicates one time , it can be shown by m.group(1) *the first occurence* :

```
    String s="0.1234523452345234";
    String regex="([0-9]+)\\1";
    Pattern p=Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m=p.matcher(s);
    if(m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Output :

```
2345
```

Comment: i wont accept your answer cause of the repeated occurrence as mine code had the same output so...i'd wait if someone could get the exact desired output...meanwhile i'd solve my question without regex. Thanks

Comment: well its just a try anyway , im already trying to see if i can get the exact output that you want , in that case i'll update my answer and inform you @Shubham

Comment: @MohamedKaram: Hint: "lookahead assertions".  What you want to match isn't 123123, it's 123 *that has 123 after it*.

Comment: Yes exactly i just have to print m.group(0)

Comment: ...or, just match `"([0-9]+)(?=\\1)"`.