# filter all words containing duplicate characters

Tags: regex, linux

I need to filter all words out of a file that have duplicate characters.

Ive been stuck for a couple of days trying to figure this out.

This is what ive got so far to find a 5 letter string but ive still got words with duplicate letters showing up...

Any help would be appreciated

```
cat /file | grep -Eow '\w{5}' | grep -v '\(.\)(.\)\1' | sort -u
```

Comment: It should be `grep -v '\(.\).*\1'`

Comment: Your question is ambiguous: do you count `bob` as having duplicate characters or do you only count words like `odd`?

Comment: Note also that any use of backreferences makes the regex "irregular". While that shouldn't cause a problem here (in fact, I wouldn't be surprised if it's even more efficient than writing a 256-way alternation for an actual "regular" version of the expression), be aware that **in general** it can cause regexes to evaluate in exponential time rather than linear time.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Input file
$ cat file
aabc
123
1233

# Filter out repeating characters
$ grep -Ev "(.)\1" file
123

# Show only lines with repeating characters
$ grep -E "(.)\1" file
aabc
1233
```

This previous question explains how to do this using regex: [Regex to find repeating numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507982/regex-to-find-repeating-numbers)

Detailed explanations:

- `grep -E` Use (extended) regex to match lines with grep
- `grep -v` Invert match so unmatching rows are displayed
- `.` regex match any character
- `( )` regex group
- `\1` match the previous groups one time, in this case any character which repeats.

Also, https://regex101.com/ is an easy way to construct a regex for your purpose. Create a few test cases and check that it works as you write the regex.

Comment: The `+` is useless if you aren't caring about highlighting or using `-o`

Comment: Great point, the plus is superfluous. I removed it from the answer. Thanks. That is, assuming the regex is only used for matching (as the OP is asking about here). If anyone wants to use the match group `\1+` would match 2 or more repeating characters.