# Regex to find three or more repeated number except 999 in Java

Tags: java, regex

Need help to stop user from entering phone number with three or more repeated digits except 999.

Phone number could be 10 digit to 25 digit.

Bad Input:

- 8**777**267331
- 000
- **6666**7878763

Exception:

- 767886655**999**

I tried --> `\b(\d)\3+\b` but looks that is not right.

Comment: Have already tried some pattern? If so, would you include it in your question please.

Comment: I looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507982/regex-to-find-repeating-numbers and patterns like \b(\d)\1+\b but didnt help

Comment: I find the requirement strange. Is this really what you want? Why can't there be 3 repeated digits in a phone number?

Comment: @Henry presumably homework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a try with

```
^(?:([0-8])(?!\1\1)|9){10,25}$
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/urUq4a/2)

Or something like this

```
^(?!.*?([0-8])\1\1)\d{10,25}$
```

[Another demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qzaw9f/3)

---

Digits are [captured](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in first *group*. A negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is used to check for [backrefernce](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) `\1`.

Comment: Thank You @bobble bubble.  The second one helps.  what if instead 0f 999 the allowed digits are 888

Comment: @AvatarGirase Welcome:) For `888` allowed like this: [`^(?!.*?([0-79])\1\1)\d{10,25}$`](https://regex101.com/r/VYA1uI/1) or first one: [`^(?:(\d)(?!\1\1)|8){10,25}$`](https://regex101.com/r/qujU6N/1) (a bit simplified/shortened)

Comment: Works like  a charm @bobble bubble. Thank You for the lightning fast response. Do you have any book that I can take a look or any suggestion from where I should learn this.

Comment: yw:) actually I learned the most while working a lot with regexes and here by answering and studying but if you like books: [Jeffrey Fridl - Mastering Regular Expressions](https://www.amazon.de/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124) - websites: [RexEgg](https://www.rexegg.com/), [Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) and for testing [Regex101](https://regex101.com/), [Regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester) (.NET), [RegexPlanet](https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) (Java)

Comment: could you please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72957182/regex-to-stop-user-from-entering-first-three-repeated-digit-except-888

Answer (score 1):

Please check this.

```
([0-8])\1{2}
```

I think this can help you. This is simpler and faster. If you have other questions, please.
Good luck.

[image]

Comment: Read the question carefully.  The OP wants to match 3 digits **except** "999".  Your matches 3 digits **including** "999".  Also presenting your answer as a screenshot is unhelpful for programmers who have impaired vision.

Comment: ok.  Please use ([0-8])\1{2}