# Regex to stop user from entering first three repeated digit except 888

Tags: java, regex

I need help in stopping a user from entering a phone number that has repeated first three digit except 888.

Phone number should  be between 10 digits to 25 digits.

Example.
Good Data

88876565451
7687987555

Bad Data
666879876577
4448765654567
I tried --> \b(\d)\3+\b but looks that is not right.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried --> \b(\d)\3+\b a and /(\d)\1{2,1}/ but looks didnt help

Answer (score 2):

For this one try e.g.

```
^(?:8|(\d)(?!\1\1))\d{9,24}$
```

[Here is the demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/g0q0b9/1)

The first character is either `8` or any digit that's not followed two times by [itself](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).
Length requirement is reduced by one as we already match one digit at the start.